# Custom height of UICollectionViewCell ignored

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've setup a UICollectionView as shown below.
I'm trying to set a custom cell height so that the collection fits 3 cells on-screen before having to scroll.
However, that customization effort doesn't work or seems to be ignored.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```swift
class CoopOverviewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var CampaignBrandSliderBackground: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CampaignBrandSlider: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var CampaignCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // TODO: load real data and replace with campaign model
    let campaignImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "icon-black")!,UIImage(named: "icon-white")!,UIImage(named: "icon-black")!,UIImage(named: "icon-white")!]
    let apiService = APIService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CampaignBrandSliderBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        // do other stuff...

        // Conform to UICollectionViewDelegate Protocol:
        CampaignCollectionView.dataSource = self
        CampaignCollectionView.delegate = self


        // Adjust Layout of CollectionViewCell: set cell height so that the collection fits 3 cells
        var cellLayout = self.CampaignCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        cellLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.CampaignCollectionView.frame.size.width, height: self.CampaignCollectionView.frame.size.height/3)
```

// ???: custom height seems to get ignored
        }

```
    // Conform to UICollectionViewDataSource Protocol:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return campaignImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let campaignCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CampaignTileViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CampaignTileViewCellController
        campaignCell.CampaignBackgroundImage.image = campaignImages[indexPath.item]

        return campaignCell
    }
```

Comment: it might be that you need an invalidateLayout call, try it after setting cell heights.

Also changing flow layout seems like a little bit of overkill, you can simply use sizeForItemAt delegate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an **Estimate Size** property of **UICollectionView** which is restricting custom height to be set. You can update its value from storyboard. Select **UICollectionView** -> **Size Inspector** -> **Estimate Size** and set its value to **None**. That way your custom height will work like charm!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add one more extension `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in this view controller. Now you will have to add few callback functions as I mentioned below.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:<your width here>  , height: collectionView.view.bounds.height/3)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in viewController and then you can try with following code:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let marginsAndInsets = inset * 2 + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)

        //set inset, minimumInteritemSpacing and cellsPerRow globally

        let itemSize = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)

        return CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        //return UIEdgeInsets.zero
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0);
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0 //minimumInteritemSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0 //minimumInteritemSpacing
    }
```